# Relation with DB size and performance

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any relation between DB size and performance in my case:

There is a table in my Oracle DB that is used for logging. Now it has almost close to over 120 million rows and increases at a rate of 1000 rows per min. Each row has 6-7 columns with basic string data.

It is for our client. We never take any data from there but we might need that in case of any issues. However its fine if we clean up every month or so.

However the actual issue is will it affect performance of other transactional tables in the same db? Assuming the disk space as unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

If 1000 rows/minute are being inserted into this table then about 40 million rows would be added per month. If this table has indexes I'd say that the biggest issue will be that eventually index maintenance will become a burden on the system, so in that case I'd expect performance to be affected.

This table seems like a good candidate for partitioning. If it's partitioned on the date/time that each row is added, with each partition containing one month's worth of data, maintenance would be much simpler. The partitioning scheme can be set up so that partitions are created automatically as needed (assuming you're on Oracle 11 or higher), and then when you need to drop a month's worth of data you can just drop the partition containing that data, which is a quick operation which doesn't burden the system with a large number of DELETE operations.

Best of luck.

Comment: let alone the delete section otherwise while using data in other tables of same DB will it have any issue. also will performance be affected if you're keeping on inserting into the same log table.

Comment: Deletions from a table which is not partitioned can take a long time, and can negatively impact performance. I've fought this battle before and have found that the best solution is to partition the table, use "local" indexes (indexes where the index entries which relate to rows stored in a given partition are stored in the same partition), and to drop entire partitions rather than doing massive numbers of individual row deletions. Best of luck.